# Excel - Using an Address to copy over an entire column including blank spaces

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, copy-paste, excel-2003, vba

What I'm trying to do is scan over every header on one sheet (the headers are located in "1:1"), find a header called "Dealer Code", then copy that entire column to another sheet.

My current problem is that there are blanks in the Dealer Code column so the selection stops. I would work from the bottom of the sheet upward to avoid this, but since the header cell is stored in an address, I can't extract the column letter.

There a way I can include blanks in my selection, or extract the column letter and work upwards?

If I'm approaching the problem very inconveniently, please let me know! I want to learn as much as possible.

Below is my code. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'Copies over Dealer Codes
With Sheets("Raw Data").Range("1:1")
Set c = .Find("Dealer Code", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = c.Address
    Do
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
End If

Sheets("Raw Data").Range(firstAddress).Select
Sheets("Raw Data").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy (Sheets("Copied Data").Range("A1"))
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("1:1")
    Set c = .Find("Dealer Code")
    Dim column As String
    column = Mid(c.Address, 2, 1)
    Range(column & ":" & column).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

This selects the whole column, but is easily changed to select the elements from the 2nd row down to the end.  Since you have blanks, something like `Range(column & "2:" & column & Range(column & "65536").End(xlUp).Row).Select` works, but is a bit kludgey, I'll admit.

Other solutions may be more optimal.

Comment: Just one more question. If I put the code in twice, like below, I get a "Object variable or With block variable not set", any idea why?

Comment: @AdamY You don't need the With statement twice, as it's already set the first time.  You can even use `set c = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1").Find("Dealer Code")` and get rid of the `With/End With` lines (the example I was looking at did many more operations on the Range object, so it was more beneficial in that case).

Comment: @AdamY Actually, if you have N things to look for, instead of repeating the code N, you should make the subroutine take in two strings, one for the header to search for, and the other for the destination range... just a thought.

Comment: I got it working. My problem was that I left it as 'code' With ActiveSheet.Range("1:1") 'code' instead of 'code' With theSheetIAmActuallyUsingInThisProject.Range("1:1") 'code' Thanks for all the help!